# Which Mutations are related with which availiable upgrades in Multiplayer?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the Heart of the Swarm campaign there are some mutations that are the same as some availiable upgrades in the normal multiplayer game mode. But Most mutations are not availiable in multiplayer.

For example the mutation [Grooved Spines](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/SCUpgrade/Grooved_Spines) is also an upgrade in the **Hydralisk Den**.

I would like to play the campaign with maximum learn effect, so I would prefer to mutate my units like it would be possible in multiplayer later too.

---

### Comparison list which are *exactly the same*:

*(Enhancements that are mutations as well as upgrades are marked with an X:)*

[Mutations in the HotS campaign](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/SCUpgrade#HotS_Campaign_Upgrades) are:

```
  Adaptive Plating (Roach)
  Adrenal Overload (Zergling)
  Ancillary Carapace (Hydralisk)
X Burrow (Swarm Host)
  Burrow Charge (Ultralisk)
  Corrosive Acid (Baneling)
  Frenzy (Hydralisk)
X Grooved Spines (Hydralisk)
  Hardened Carapace (Zergling)
  Hydriodic Bile (Roach)
X Metabolic Boost (Zergling)
  Monarch Blades (Ultralisk)
  Pressurised Glands (Swarm Host)
  Rapid Incubation (Swarm Host)
  Rapid Regeneration (Mutalisk)
  Regenerative Acid (Baneling)
  Rupture (Baneling)
  Sundering Glave (Mutalisk)
  Tissue Animation (Ultralisk)
X Tunneling Claws (Roach)
  Vicious Glave (Mutalisk)
```

[Zerg Upgrades](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/SCUpgrade#Zerg_Upgrades) from multiplayer:

```
Baneling Nest
    Centrifugal Hooks (Baneling) 
Hatchery, Lair, Hive
    Burrow
    Pneumatized Carapace (Overlord, Overseer)
    Ventral Sacs (Overlord) 
Hydralisk Den
    Grooved Spines (Hydralisk)
    Muscular Augments (Hydralisk) 
Infestation Pit
    Neural Parasite (Infestor)
    Pathogen Glands (Infestor)
    Enduring Locusts (Locust) 
Roach Warren
    Glial Reconstitution (Roach)
    Tunneling Claws (Roach) 
Spawning Pool
    Adrenal Glands (Zergling)
    Metabolic Boost (Zergling) 
Ultralisk Cavern
    Chitinous Plating (Ultralisk)
    Anabolic Synthesis (Ultralisk, removed in Patch 0.16.0)
Evolution Chamber
    Melee Attacks: Level 1, Level 2, Level 3
    Missile Attacks: Level 1, Level 2, Level 3
    Ground Carapace: Level 1, Level 2, Level 3
Spire/Greater Spire
    Flyer Attacks: Level 1, Level 2, Level 3
    Flyer Carapace: Level 1, Level 2, Level 3
```

### The question is:

Which Mutations that are not exactly like Upgrades are still **related** to the multiplayer game?

Comment: "I would like to play the campaign with maximum learn effect, [...]" If you're trying to be better at the game, IMO it's better to actually play MP games rather than the campaign itself. Specifically because in the campaign, you're talking about a game mode where everything is done in a linear and scripted fashion. However, it provides a great and solid background to the ins and outs of the game, but it's not a replacement as to what you can gain by ploughing through games after games in MP.

Comment: If you want to become a great multiplayer SC2 player, then I would strongly recommend against even playing the campaign. While the campaign is a lot of fun (and I myself have played and beat it) - it is a far more effective use of your time to not play the campaign. There are custom maps you can instead use to practice your build orders and macro that are much more effective.

Comment: I disagree with Simon, you paid for the game, its a well made and fun campaign, enjoy it.  You'll hate laddering so enjoy the campaign while you still can.  I laddered to masters and quit as soon as I got there because it was so much work

Comment: Blizzard also states that you cant compare the campaign to playing online. This not only includes the units, but the game is totally different. Therefor, if you want to be a better gamer. See the answer / tips to playing Zerg.

Comment: @rubo77 You should considere posting the answer as an acutal answer instead of in the question itself.

Comment: @rubo77 I cant see the difference between simular and being the same. I think you should refreace the question. Because you have the list over the upgrades from the campaign and the list of upgrades from the multiplayer part. And the upgrade with the same name, is the same upgrade. If the name isnt on the list, then it isnt there regarding mulityplayer.

Comment: @rubo77 Remember that, when you answer to a comment, use "@name" so that person can see that you replied to a comment :)

Comment: I changed it, what I was looking for was which are **related** (sorry my english)

Comment: I think that a better English word would be **equivalent** in this case.  "What mutations are equivalent to what multi-player upgrades?"  And I agree with AtlasEU.  It would be better if you pulled most of the content out of your question and put it in a community-wiki answer instead.  I'd have addressed the wording/spelling issues by now if the answer material wasn't in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on list from the upgrades found in the HOTS campaign.
Here are the relations:

- Zerglings: Metabolic Boost (same upgrade) Adrenal Glands (+18,6%) and
  Adrenal Overload (+50%) (increased attack speed)
- Banelings: None are related
- Roaches: Tunneling Claws (Movement underground for both, but less
  regen online)
- Hydralisks: Grooved Spines (+6 in the campaign +1 online)
- Mutalisks: None are related
- Swarm Host: None are related
- Ultralisks: None are related